# One VPS, multiples services, different projects/domains

Tags: docker, nginx, vps

This is my first VPS, so I am pretty new to administrating my own box. I already have experience with a managed web server, registrars, DNS settings, etc. The basics. Now I'd like to take it a step further and manage my own VPS to run multiple services for different business and private projects.

So far I got an VPS from Contabo, updated the system, set up a new user with `sudo` rights, secured the `root` user, configured Ufw, installed Nginx with server blocks for two domains and created SSL certificates for one domain using Certbot.

Before I go on with setting up my VPS, I'd like to verify my approach for hosting multiple services for multiple domains makes sense and is a good way to go.

My goal is to host the following services on my VPS. Some of them will be used by all projects some only by a single one:

- static website hosting
- dynamic website hosting with a lightweight CMS
- send and receive emails
- Nextcloud/Owncloud
- Ghost blog

My current approach is to run all services except for Nginx and the mail server with Docker. Using Nginx as proxy to the services encapsulated in Docker.

Is this an overkill or a valid way to go forward in order to keep the system nice and clean? Since I am new to all of this, I am unsure if I also could run all of the services without using Docker but still be able to serve the different projects on different domains without messing up the system.

Furthermore, I'd like to make sure, that access to the services and the stored data is properly separated between the different tenants (projects). And of course ideally the admin of the services is kind of manageable.

Comment: I'd suggest Traefik instead of Nginx for the frontend proxy. The main benefit of this is that it is built with Docker in mind, and also it automatically registers certificates with Let's Encrypt.

Comment: On top of that, I would set up containers with a restart policy, so they all come back if you need to reboot.

Comment: I have a bunch of scripts to do this on my VPS - one per service - but equally you could just install Portainer on the host, so you have a way to control your containers and keep an eye on them. A third option would be to put them all in a Docker Compose config.

Comment: Incidentally, you can Dockerise the mail server too - just use an on-host volume for the mail spool.

Comment: Thanks for your fast reply. 
If I understand your approach correctly, you would use Traefik as reverse proxy, dockerize alle services including nginx. Even so the mail server. As far as a did my research, traefik is not able to serve http files. Therefore, I still need a web server to deliver http files.

Comment: I haven't used Traefik for a while, but I think you are right, I don't think it has a built-in web-server. It can only forward connections to listeners. If you want a general HTTP-only web server then an ordinary Apache or Nginx container would be fine, and if you want to optimize for image size, there's bound to be a "microserver" system out there.